# ionic 2 <ion-select> wrapped in a <button> design

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-select

I want the `<ion-select>` of a ionic form to look like a `<button>`.

Here is my html template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="doSubmit()" [formGroup] = "myForm" >
  <ion-item>
    <!-- <button ion-button block> -->
    <ion-select type="text" formControlName="choose" placeholder = "choose">
      <ion-option value=1>option 1</ion-option>
      <ion-option value=2>option 2</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    <!-- </button> -->
  </ion-item>
 // ... other input fields  + doSubmit() function ...
</form>
```

As it is, it works and I can manage the selection. But **I want it to look like a button**. So I added some tag `<button ion-button block></button>` around the `<select>` tags. If the `<button>` tags are uncommented, it does not work: It does not show as a button and the select functionnaly is dead. Also I naively expected it would execute as I had wished it, but it doesn't.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Could you create a class with the button's CSS, then apply that class?

Comment: well I thought about the CSS option, but I'd like to avoid that path. It seems cumbersome to maintain with the different button look according to platforms type.